# Link to libssl 0.9.8 instead of 0.9.7 in Qt for Mac

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator, libssl

I found my application compiled with Qt Creator under Mac (Qt 4.7.4 and Qt 4.8.0) is linked to `/usr/lib/libssl0.9.7`.

It is giving me a lot of SSL errors when I browse https websites from the application based on QtWebkit. The windows version of Qt is based on OpenSSL 0.9.8. I do see libssl 0.9.8 is also installed on my Mac OS Lion. How can I get Qt Creator to link against libssl 0.9.8?

Comment: How do you know it's linked to that specific version? What does otool -L <yourBinary> say?